# Google Authentication in windows phone 8.1[RT]

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-phone-8.1

I am working with windows phone 8.1[RT] application, I have use

```
  WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(new Uri(_loginUrl));
```

It will open gmail page, ask user for access or deny but when I pressed Allow it will give me below page.

And OnActivated method not called, when I pressed back it will called with User cancelled.

How to solve this problem ?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Actually it probably opens a web browser and you will need to handle the document complete and grab the Authentication code so you can exchange it for a refresh token.

Comment: Thank you DalmTo for you valuable reply . can you please explain in detail or have you any example for that  ?

Comment: Nope I use the .Net client library it handles all that for you.   I haven't tried doing it the hard way on a windows phone app.  If you get it working post the code it would be interesting to see.